# sudo apt update doesn't work

Tags: apt, update

Hi if i try `sudo apt update`, I get the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://apt.adafruit.com/raspbian wheezy InRelease
  Something wicked happened resolving 'apt.adafruit.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease                                                                
Ign:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease                                                         
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Err:5 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                 
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Does one have any ideas?

Comment: You have to be joking. `Wheezy` isn't just obsolete it is prehistoric.

Comment: Debian “wheezy” Release Information

Debian 7.11 was released June 4th, 2016. Debian 7.0 was initially released on May 4th, 2013. The release included many major changes, described in our press release and the Release Notes.

Debian 7 has been superseded by Debian 8 ("jessie").

Wheezy also benefits from Long Term Support (LTS) until the end of May 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the window when you could have easily upgraded your system: not only Debian 7 Wheezy packages have been removed from the repo, but Debian 8 Jessie is gone as well. Debian 9 Stretch will be on its way to the grave soon.

You could try to dist-upgrade directly to Stretch (replace `wheezy` with `stretch` in your sources.list file and run `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0`), but the chances of success are pretty slim IMO. You'll need to backup your user data and install a modern system (Debian 11 Bullseye) from scratch.

There are ways to install and upgrade packages on ancient Debian systems (http://archive.debian.org/dists keeps packages released since 1998), but you must have good reasons to do so and have backups ready because there will be a high chance of ruining your system with broken packages (Debian and Pi OS are not fully compatible).